# cost of Adding Social Feature to your game such Creating guilds/guild chat

Tags: software-engineering, databases, social, free-to-play

I'm making a f2p game in unity C#. The game currently has no social features.

I would like to have players to have their own accounts and also a guild tab. This tab is where they can create a guild and invite other players to the roster and being able to chat with each other.

Also would like to add leader boards for individual and guild rankings.

Was just wondering if any programmers can give me a estimate on labor to be able to make that feature in a game and how long roughly it would take.

I'm think I will need a mySql and php. I'm not really familiar with how it works.

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: I hope you are still in the design process. Ideally you do not want to add features like this late in the development process. It can cause quite a bit of work for developers that did not expect a feature like this to be implemented.

Comment: @UnderscoreZero Agreed. Features like this should be a core implementation, not a "plug-in". This would be a very large change to a game system lacking it.

Answer (score 3):

There's a simple formula you can use:

`estimatedCost = (hoursRequired * costPerHour) + additionalCosts`

The `hoursRequired` can range anywhere from a few hours for someone advanced making something very simple to hundreds of hours for someone very amateur making something very complex. The `costPerHour` will vary depending on the number of developers and their wages. `additionalCosts` include things like pre-built solutions, libraries to support certain functionality and so on.

Unfortunately only you will know the details of the variables, so only you can compute `estimatedCost`.